# Why am I getting two instances of my Singleton EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I'm doing some experiments to help solidify my understanding of @Singleton EJBs.

I have implemented an EJB called TotalBean like this:

```
@Singleton
public class TotalBean implements TotalBeanLocal {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return toString();
    }
}
```

I have it injected into a message-driven bean like this:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/TestQueue", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class TotalMessageBean implements MessageListener {

    @EJB
    TotalBeanLocal totalBean;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("In message-driven bean, totalBean is " + totalBean.getName());
    }
}
```

And also into a Servlet like this:

```
public class TaxTest extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    TotalBeanLocal totalBean;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("In servlet, totalBean is " + totalBean.getName());
        // Display page, etc.
    }
}
```

The EJB and message-driven bean are deployed in one application, and the servlet in another application.

My expectation is that my GlassFish log will contain the same bean name every time the singleton bean is used, since just one singleton will be created across my entire domain.  Instead, though, the logs indicate there are at least two instances of my "singleton" bean:

- INFO: In servlet, totalBean is TotalBean@**1b8e347**
- INFO: In message-driven bean, totalBean is TotalBean@1b8e347
- INFO: In servlet, totalBean is TotalBean@1b8e347
- INFO: In message-driven bean, totalBean is TotalBean@**16ba6b2**
- INFO: In servlet, totalBean is TotalBean@1b8e347
- INFO: In message-driven bean, totalBean is TotalBean@1b8e347
- INFO: In servlet, totalBean is TotalBean@1b8e347

Can anybody help me understand the fault in my understanding of @Singleton EJBs?

Thanks!

-----Scott.

Comment: if you set some instance variables i thin those shoud be same. i would guess the 2 instances you see are simply some pproxy

Comment: Instance variables are different too; that's how I noticed the problem.  I think that returning the name from inside the object will return the name of object itself and not one of the proxies.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you have two applications and that the singleton is different in each application?

> The EJB and message-driven bean are deployed in one application, and the servlet in another application.

That's according to the spec http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html:

> A singleton session bean **is instantiated once per application** and exists for the lifecycle of the application. Singleton session beans are designed for circumstances in which a single enterprise bean instance is shared across and concurrently accessed by clients.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  You can see from the logs I posted though that the singleton instance is initially the same in both applications, then later changes in just the message-driven application.